# Equivalent of comma operator in Java?

Tags: java, code-generation

I am trying to do a source transformation on some Java code that results in code where for every expression, a method is called if the expression is evaluated.

(The use case is a simplistic line coverage measure. I've done this sort of thing before in JavaScript: `<my-expression>` becomes `(covered("path/to/file.js", 12), <my-expression>)` or something, where 12 is the line number of the expression).

Java doesn't have a comma operator. I thought about wrapping expressions in a method call, e.g. my `covered` function would be declared `public static <T> T covered(String file, int line, T expr)` and return its third argument, so I could write `covered("path/to/file.java", 12, myExpression())` but it doesn't work for expressions that have type `void`.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Evil code is okay; this is generated code.

Comment: Coverage analysis to the granularity of an expression seems a bit excessive to me.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, this is just nice because I could do everything in one place (the code that handles expressions). Otherwise I'd have to handle different kinds of statements differently. Not a huge deal, but still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I see the problem, now.)

The only *context* in Java where a void expression can legally occur is when it is a statement expression, or the 1st or 3rd part in a classic `for` statement. So:

- If the expression is used as an expression statement:

  ```
  covered(...); <my-expression>;
  ```
- If the expression is used as the 1st or 3rd part of a `for`,

  ```
  covered(...), <my-expression>
  ```
- Otherwise

  ```
  covered(..., <my-expression>)
  ```

  or some such.  (This requires an overload of `covered` for each primitive type, and also an overload with signature `<T> overload(..., <T>)`.)

I think this can be determined purely based on the syntax.  No type analysis or method overload resolution is required to figure out whether a void method is actually being called.